# Check if a specific alertdialogbox exists android

Tags: android, udp

I have a UDP server that sends data to client. The display of data (in client side) is with the use of dialogbox. The problem is if I have multiple send of same data, there'll be multiple dialogboxes with same value. I want to remove the other dialogboxes to retain the dialogbox with unique value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
 {  
   return;
 }
```

and when task complete use **dialog.dismiss();**

Comment: how can i check if that dialog box contains the same value?

Answer (score 0):

What about using some sort of Set based on a unique identifier of the data that you receive? The identifier should be the same with multiple "send" of the same data.

```
private AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context.this);
private Set<Integer> mShownDialogs = new HashSet<Integer>();

public void onReceive(final MyData data) {
    final Integer dataHash = data.getUniqueHash();
    if (!mShownDialogs.contains(dataHash)) {
        mShownDialogs.add(dataHash);

        mDialogBuilder.setTitle(data.getTitle());
        mDialogBuilder.setMessage(data.getMessage());
        AlertDialog dialog = mDialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // If I want to show a dialog with the same dataHash some
                // time in the future, I should remove from set.
                mShownDialogs.remove(dataHash);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        // Discard the data?
    }
}
```